# Alternatives to Linux logger

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, archlinux

I received an application code that can be run on Linux kernel 4.4.60 as below cmd - per their app note :-

```
/usr/sbin/server_application | logger -t tag &
```

However my kernel does not have the logger inbuilt.
Does anyone know any alternatives to the logger, using which I can post the tagged text to the stdout?

Edit: Correcting the question-
Does anyone know any alternatives to the logger, using which I can post the tagged text to the **syslog**?

Comment: That command is piping the `stdout` to logger. If you want the output to go to `stdout` then just remove the pipe and `logger` command.

Comment: If you need daemon mode, use _nohup_.

Comment: 1. Copy logger source code. 2. Compile. 3. Use it. What other alternatives are you searching for? You can write your own program that has the same funcionality. `to the syslog?` Are you sure you are using syslog? Because I am pretty sure archlinux moved to journalctl. logger is from `core/util-linux` package, if you don't have logger on archlinux, then you also don't have `dmesg` and `swapon` and `more` and even `mount` nor `kill`?

Comment: Such program is really easy to write, like `while (getline(&line, ...) { syslog(LOG_INFO, "%s", line); }`. And if you really want, you can send messages to `/dev/log` yourself, with some `socat` or similar.

Comment: "Are you sure you are using syslog? Because I am pretty sure archlinux moved to journalctl." - What is the journalctl mapped to in the file system?
The kernel I am using has mount, kill, dmesg etc. but the logger. I am building it separately and will install and see if it works.

Comment: Run `nohup /path/to/your/program &`. You will get logs in *nohup.out*.